# Using Rattle package on R

Tags: r, neural-network, rattle

I am trying to get comfortable with the 'rattle' package in R. I am having issues building a neural network using this package.

I have a training data set of 140 columns and 200000 rows and a target variable that takes values from 0-4 depending on the class it belongs to. It is a classic pattern classification problem.

When I load my data into rattle, the option of 'neural network' under 'Model' tab is de-activated. Is there a pre-requisite that my data doesn't fulfil?

I know I can use neural network specific packages to implement one, but the situation requires me to use rattle.

Any clues/suggestions are very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably because your "target" variable is "categoric"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your dataset contains all neumeric values. Else go to data tab and select 'ignore' to ignore that feature for further calculation.

Check this link if you want to do the same without using the GUI
http://www.r-bloggers.com/visualizing-neural-networks-in-r-update/